# Thread pool for fast bursts of short threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

My application captures network packets (like wireshark) in a capture thread and allows other components to register callback functions with filter conditions to captured packets.
At the moment I start a thread for each callback subscriber each time I capture a packet like this:

```
foreach (CCallbackFilterCondition hCallback in m_ahSubscribers)
{
  // Raise callbacks in separate threads so they don't block the capture thread
  ParameterizedThreadStart hPTS = new ParameterizedThreadStart(hCallback.raiseIfMeetsConditions);
  Thread hCallbackThread = new Thread(hPTS);
  hCallbackThread.Start(hPacket);
}
```

Each of these threads will probably run only a few milliseconds, but can run longer depending on the callback method. They are started each time a packet is captured, which can be very frequent.

My question now is the following: How high is the overhead of starting a new thread? Would it be better to use a pool of constantly running threads instead of creating new threads in high frequency? If my callbacks are slow, this may lead to starting needing many new threads while the old ones are still running, so I would need a high amount of threads in the pool, so I would probably need a pool that grows dynamicly. But that could lead to many idle threads if traffic dies down or high load subscribers unsubscribe. What are your suggestions?

Comment: `Paralell.For` and `Paralell.ForEach` is designed for this purpose only(if your task is not contented)

Comment: @dcastro So what's the problem? Why not dispatch all and add it in temp collection in a single thread, then do a `Paralell.ForEach` with temp collection. Am I misssing something?

Comment: He doesn't seem to want to wait for those threads to finish, so there's no need for a temp collection. He seems to be looking for a "fire and forget" approach. A `Paralell.ForEach` ends when all tasks end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I can't use Paralell.ForEach since I'm bound to .Net 3.5 because of the framework I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use .NET's `ThreadPool`. Don't worry about the need for more threads, or the need to kill useless idle threads: the ThreadPool uses an Hill-Climbing heuristic to figure out the optimal number of threads to achieve maximum performance.

Read more about how the ThreadPool works here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx

Comment: `ThreadPool` will die if you queue 1000's of tasks. any other task queued will be affected due to this. :(

Comment: What do you mean by "die"? From what I've researched, there seems to be no limit to how many workitems you can queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095805/maximum-queued-elements-in-threadpool-queueuserworkitem

Comment: There is no limit to queue, I mean it'll perform poor note my second point **any other task queued will be affected due to this**. This is what I mean

Comment: I can't seem to find anything related to that... but `Parallel.ForEach` uses the ThreadPool internally anyway.

Comment: Of course `TPL` uses `ThreadPool` internally. but main difference is they schedule the call to threadpool in right time

Comment: Thanks, I will try ThreadPool and do some performance checking

Comment: As far as I know, the only performance difference between `Parallel`'s and `ThreadPool`'s scheduling, is that `Parallel.ForEach` does intelligent partitioning for your collection of workitems. This would be relevant if he had hundred of subcribers, and he wanted to partition work among those subscribers. In this case, the problem lies in the amount of packets received, not in the amount of subscribers, so he can't use intelligent partition to divide his work.